# is MIPS an assembly language or machine language

Tags: mips

I have found resources referring to MIPS as both machine language and assembly language. They are 2 different types, machine language consists of only 0s and 1s, while assembly one deploys instructions such as add, sub, etc.

Why do people keep confusing those 2 concepts?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture), it's neither of those.

Comment: The ones and zeros represent instructions that cause add, sub, and, etc...Assembly language is just a way for humans to deal with the ones and zeros.  The assembler takes the assembly language and makes machine code and data from it.

Comment: @old_timer I think the distinction is that a processor can have multiple assemblers with different syntax but typically only one instruction set.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> is MIPS an assembly language or machine language

That's the wrong question - it isn't an "or". It's a little bit like asking "Is Ford a car or a truck?".

MIPS is a processor *[architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture)* and so:

- there is MIPS assembly language
- *and* there is MIPS machine code
- *and* there are MIPS architecture CPUs

[Credit to *brhans* for the Wikipedia link for the MIPS architecture.]

Comment: And in addition to those three meanings there is also Millions of Instruction Per Second.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen - Hi, yes. I thought other meanings were out-of-scope, given the focus of the question (i.e. assembly vs. machine code) so I stuck specifically to the meaning of MIPS in the question. However for future readers, they should note that "MIPS" has multiple interpretations, including the one you mentioned. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 7):

There's no confusion. Assembly language is simply a human-readable representation of machine language. There is a one-to-one correspondence between instructions in assembly language and instructions in machine language.

Comment: Usually. The MIPS assembler can generate machine code that isn't present in the source code. For example, the R2000 branch delay slots can be automatically filled.

Comment: Consequently, is MIPS an assembly language or a machine language?

Comment: @jonk: The MIPS assembler is either inserting NOPs or reordering instructions that did appear in the source code, right? But in any case, that's not what we're referring to when we talk about the characteristics of "assembly language" in general.

Comment: @TjhThon: The input to the assembler is "assembly language", and the output is "machine language". The concept of what "MIPS" is covers both.

Comment: I wasn't criticizing. Just noting a nuance. (I met and worked with Dr. Hennessey back in 1985-1986. So I have a small bit of memory of those experiences.)

Comment: Per a guy writing in assembly during the 1960s as a teenager, the use of assembler-macros is a game-changer. He used the MetaAssembler behind the Max Pavlevsky SDS 560.

Comment: Ideally one to one, not counting the directives and other fluff.  and pseudo instructions.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf: Well, sure. A good macro assembler can greatly extend the power of assembly-language programming. The MACRO-11 assembler for the PDP-11 was powerful enough to implement a compile-time stack that allowed us to implement "structured programming" keywords such as "if-then-else-endif" and various looping constructs. I learned it back in the late 1970s, and I've used the technique in my assembly language programming ever since.

Answer (score 1):

When most people learn MIPS, they are learning the assembly language with the nice commands and registers. This gets assembled into machine code which the processer uses. The idea of using assembly is the same reason why most people code in higher level languages rather than C (for example). There is a little overhead but it becomes easier to understand and you can be more elaborate.

Answer (score -2):

MIPS is a way of thinking about implementing algorithms in state machines, promulgated by Hennessey.

And from the John Hennessy Wikipedia page

Hennessy became a Stanford faculty member in 1977. In 1981, he began the MIPS project to investigate RISC processors, and in 1984, he used his sabbatical year to found MIPS Computer Systems Inc. to commercialize the technology developed by his research. In 1987, he became the Willard and Inez Kerr Bell Endowed Professor of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science

Comment: This is a bit thin for an answer.  Could elaborate, please.

Comment: How many people on this planet know what "MIPS" is? Many of us in the SE network know, but for the general public and many new members they are lost. Please define such acronyms at least once per answer so we are all on the same page.